# How to cast time columns and find timedelta with condition in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a column Time which is non null object and I cannot convert it to timedelta or datetime.

```
     Time             msg
12:29:36.306000      Setup
12:29:36.507000      Alerting
12:29:38.207000      Service
12:29:39.194000      Setup
12:30:05.773000      Alerting
12:30:06.205000      Service
12:32:07.315000      Setup
12:32:17.194000      Service
12:32:26.889000      Setup
12:36:06.274000      Alerting
12:36:08.523000      Service
12:37:59.200000      Setup
12:47:10.652000      Alerting
12:47:43.921000      Setup
```

When I type df.info(), I got that a 'Time' column is non null object and I couldn't convert it to timedelta or datetime(for this it's obvious why I can't do it). So, what's is the solution to find the difference between consecutive msg (time delta), but if is timedelta < 5sec than pass.
Output:

```
     Time             msg         diff
12:29:36.306000      Setup         
12:29:36.507000      Alerting      
12:29:38.207000      Service
12:29:39.194000      Setup
12:30:05.773000      Alerting
12:30:06.205000      Service
12:32:07.315000      Setup
12:32:17.194000      Service
12:32:26.889000      Setup
12:36:06.274000      Alerting    6.30***
12:36:08.523000      Service     
12:37:59.200000      Setup
12:47:10.652000      Alerting    11.02***    
12:47:43.921000      Setup
```

I've tried with something like this:

```
df['diff'] = (df['Time']df['Time'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

But I didn't know to write condition for 5sec interval.

Comment: If use `df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])` it return error?

Comment: Yes.    
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <type 'datetime.time'>

Comment: Then use `df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think first need convert to `str` and then call [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

Then get [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and comapre with `5s`.

Last for new column use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) by mask:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))

df['diff'] = df['Time'].diff()
df['mask'] = df['Time'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(5, unit='s')
print (df)
              Time       msg            diff   mask
0  12:29:36.306000     Setup             NaT  False
1  12:29:36.507000  Alerting 00:00:00.201000  False
2  12:29:38.207000   Service 00:00:01.700000  False
3  12:29:39.194000     Setup 00:00:00.987000  False
4  12:30:05.773000  Alerting 00:00:26.579000   True
5  12:30:06.205000   Service 00:00:00.432000  False
6  12:32:07.315000     Setup 00:02:01.110000   True
7  12:32:17.194000   Service 00:00:09.879000   True
8  12:32:26.889000     Setup 00:00:09.695000   True
9  12:36:06.274000  Alerting 00:03:39.385000   True
10 12:36:08.523000   Service 00:00:02.249000  False
11 12:37:59.200000     Setup 00:01:50.677000   True
12 12:47:10.652000  Alerting 00:09:11.452000   True
13 12:47:43.921000     Setup 00:00:33.269000   True
```

---

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
diff = df['Time'].diff()
mask = df['Time'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(5, unit='s')
df['new'] = diff.where(mask)
print (df)
              Time       msg             new
0  12:29:36.306000     Setup             NaT
1  12:29:36.507000  Alerting             NaT
2  12:29:38.207000   Service             NaT
3  12:29:39.194000     Setup             NaT
4  12:30:05.773000  Alerting 00:00:26.579000
5  12:30:06.205000   Service             NaT
6  12:32:07.315000     Setup 00:02:01.110000
7  12:32:17.194000   Service 00:00:09.879000
8  12:32:26.889000     Setup 00:00:09.695000
9  12:36:06.274000  Alerting 00:03:39.385000
10 12:36:08.523000   Service             NaT
11 12:37:59.200000     Setup 00:01:50.677000
12 12:47:10.652000  Alerting 00:09:11.452000
13 12:47:43.921000     Setup 00:00:33.269000
```

Comment: It depends what is question - maybe yes, maybe not is necessary create new topic.

Comment: I have one more quastion if you don't mind. I can create a new Q topic.
What If I have to use that 5sec condition just if I have two 'Setup' value of msg without 'Alerting' value between them. In case if Alerting is between two Setup value in msg, than just calculate timedelta as it's normal.
For example, seventh and eight rows would be NaT in your code, but other would have timedelta.

Comment: It seems not so easy, maybe you can create new question. Why not selected `6,7,8` row?