# Sum of pandas dataframe time format values

Tags: python, pandas

I had tried to sum multiple values of same format 'hh:mm:ss' using pandas data series and it's data type is datetime.time/object.but it getting error.could you please guide me best way.

Here is the code:

```
    import pandas as pd  
    school_diesel =pd.read_excel(r'*********************** Diesel Log 23-09-2019 17_59_05.xlsx',heading=[1,2])  
    school_running = pd.read_excel(r'*************Daily Log 23-09-2019 18_09_41.xlsx',0)  
    school_diesel.columns = school_diesel.iloc[0] # replace headings with next row values  
school_running.columns = school_running.iloc[0] # replace headings with next row values  
school_running.columns  
school_diesel.columns  
school_diesel.drop(school_diesel.head(1).index, inplace=True) #drop first row of the table- as this repeated heading  
school_running.drop(school_running.head(1).index, inplace=True) #drop first row of the table- as this repeated heading
```

data types of each field is:

```
input: school_running.info()  

output: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  

Int64Index: 12469 entries, 1 to 12469  
Data columns (total 25 columns):  
Sno                       12468 non-null object  
City                    12467 non-null object
Zone                    12467 non-null object
Branch                  12467 non-null object
Building Code           12383 non-null object
 Branch Type            12305 non-null object
AC or Non AC            11405 non-null object
 Student Strength       12467 non-null object
Company Name            12381 non-null object
Gen SNo                 12467 non-null object
Capacity KVA            12381 non-null object
Fuel Capacity           12467 non-null object
Last Diesel Purchase    12467 non-null object
Purchase Qty            12467 non-null object
Amount                  12467 non-null object
Last Fuel Filled        12467 non-null object
Filling Qty             12467 non-null object
Diesel Opening Qty      12467 non-null object
Generator On Date       12467 non-null object
Generator Off Date      12467 non-null object
Running Hours           12466 non-null object
Consumed Units          12466 non-null object
Diesel Consumed         12466 non-null object
Diesel Balance Qty      12466 non-null object
Remarks                 6267 non-null object
dtypes: object(25)
memory usage: 1.3+ MB
```

error occured at line :

```
school_running['Running Hours'].sum()

error is :

----> 1 school_running['Running Hours'].sum()  
**
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

**Expected output is to sum of total Running Hours.**

**Time data is : **

```
school_running['Running Hours'].head(10)

1     00:00:00
2     00:00:00
3     00:25:00
4     00:00:00
5     00:00:00
6     00:00:00
7     00:00:00
8     00:00:00
9     00:00:00
10    01:20:00
Name: Running Hours, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert them into Timedeltas.  Below will give you total seconds

```
df['Running Hours'] = df['Running Hours'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[-1:] + x[:x.find("-")])

pd.to_timedelta(df['Running Hours']).sum().total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, While executing above code error is generated i.e ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: @krishna I've edited the answer.  I guess you need to convert it to a string first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694396/how-to-cast-time-columns-and-find-timedelta-with-condition-in-python-pandas

Comment: appriciate your support in solving this problem.i tried with code given by you but doesn't worked and giving the error as " Only leading negative signes are allowed".

Comment: You have negative signs at the end and you need to move them to the beginning.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: if executed the above code an error is generated as "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.       and checked the output for negative values                                                                                                                                                                                ```1     000:00:0
2     000:00:0
3     000:25:0
4     000:00:0
5     000:00:0
6     000:00:0
7     000:00:0
8     000:00:0
9     000:00:0
10    001:20:0
Name: Running Hours, dtype: object```

Comment: It's worked now, due to empty cells it got generated error.