# How to convert and sum durations?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with different durations in it. I am trying to sum the durations by their "Owning Group" and am having some issues. The first issue I am having is converting my Duration column to timedelta format. I keep getting the below error:

```
    ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>
```

Using code:

```
    incidents['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(incidents['Duration'])
```

Once they are converted to timedelta, am I able to just sum them or is there a specific way it needs done? I just want it to be formatted as total hours:minutes:seconds...it will be well over 24 hours.

Some snapshots of the data:

```
          Month  Day  Year             Duration Business Impact Owning Group
    0    January    1  2020             09:02:00        00:00:00       AppDev   
    2    January   11  2020             03:29:00        03:29:00       AppDev   
    7    January   31  2020             01:56:00        01:56:00       AppDev   
    8   February    3  2020                  NaN        00:00:00       AppDev   
    9   February    8  2020             01:13:00        01:13:00       AppDev   
    10  February    8  2020             03:44:00        03:44:00       AppDev   
    11  February   10  2020  1900-01-01 23:16:00        02:43:00          EWS   
    15  February   19  2020             05:59:00        05:59:00       AppDev   
    16  February   18  2020             04:00:00        04:00:00          EWS   
    17  February   17  2020             05:02:00        05:02:00       AppDev   
    19  February   25  2020             03:19:00        03:19:00          EWS
```

Line 11 should be 47:16:00 and I know the datetime.time format won't allow over 24 hours.

Example of what I would like summed given the info above:

```
    Owning Group  Total Duration
       EWS           54:35:00
```

Eventually I would do the same thing for the business impact.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer cover the appropriate fix?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694396/how-to-cast-time-columns-and-find-timedelta-with-condition-in-python-pandas

Comment: @LTheriault I think this may work! I've been searching all morning for a question on here that answered it and all I could find was differences between datetime.time values. I'll give this a try!

Comment: @LTheriault Update: it gave me this error when I used that suggestion to convert to a timedelta: "ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number"

Comment: what is this value: `1900-01-01`?

Comment: @kederrac that goes with line 11. It's supposed to be a total of 47:16:00 but since it won't allow it to display anything over 24 hours so it gets displayed as such.

Comment: your column Duration is of type string?

Comment: @kederrac incidents.dtypes
Out[36]: 
Month                           object
Day                              int64
Year                             int64
Duration                        object
Business Impact                 object
Owning Group                    object
Affected Application            object
Details                         object
Serviced                datetime64[ns]
Requires Followup               object
Followup                        object
Unnamed: 11                    float64
Unnamed: 12                     object